# What is the relation between the linear transformation B and C?

Tags: transformation

If  $\left\{ \left. {{x}_{1}},{{x}_{2}},...,{{x}_{n}} \right\} \right.$and $\left\{ \left. {{y}_{1}},{{y}_{2}},...,{{y}_{n}} \right\} \right.$ are basis of a vector space V ,and for every $j=1,2,...n$

$B{{x}_{j}}=\sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}{{{a}_{ij}}{{x}_{i}}}$    and $C{{y}_{j}}=\sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}{{{a}_{ij}}{{y}_{i}}}$.
What is the relation between the linear transformation B and C ?

my intuition is that they are similar .I tried to subtrabct B and C .Thats so far

Answer (score 1):

If $\varphi: V\to V$ is the linear transformation defined by $\varphi(x_i)=y_i$, then
\begin{equation}
\varphi^{-1}\circ C\circ\varphi(x_j) = \varphi^{-1}\circ C y_j = \varphi^{-1}\left(\sum_j a_{i j} y_i\right) = \sum_j a_{i j} x_i = B x_j
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{equation}
B = \varphi^{-1}\circ C\circ\varphi
\end{equation}